# How to get vertex back to its original position?

Tags: vertices

Sorry, I'm really new and do not know how to word this very well. Somehow during this I grabbed and moved this vertex without realizing and now I am too far in to undo it. I need to find a way to get it back to its original spot in the loop without moving any of the others around it. I tried hitting W and messing with a few of the tools but I haven't found one that works yet. Hopefully there is a quick fix for this. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is it oriented to a particular axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its only moved on the y-axis... you could press "n" to get the properties window on the right side... and copy the y-position of another vertice in the ring to that vertice.

Comment: Thanks, due to it being angled I was able to use your idea to get the Z and the Y, but the X I couldn't find a point that lined up correctly. I will just eyeball it from here. I'm just starting so I don't think this will need to be perfect.

Comment: Woops, I'm bad at this. I just realized that the corner at the top right is the X I'm looking for since I never rotated this mesh. So you solved my question perfectly and now everything feels right in the world knowing its perfectly aligned again. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear! Have fun...